Injecting content script allows CORS fetch in service worker
I am trying to fetch https://www.google.com. It responds without Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, so my service worker is blocked by CORS policy due to being in a different domain. This behavior is expected.
However, if I inject a content script to https://www.google.com/*, then my service worker can fetch the URL. In other words, it has the same effect as adding https://www.google.com/* to host_permissions. Why is it the case? Is there any difference between the two ways?
Here is my code:
manifest.js:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Content Script Test",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Test.",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.google.com/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

background.js:
fetch("https://www.google.com").then((response) => response.text()).then(console.log);

content.js: Empty

It's because the content_scripts declaration grants the host permissions for sites in matches by design in order to enable injection.
